# Biased autocomplete in SOLR

Tags: solr

For an E-commerce website, we want SOLR to give suggestions while the user is typing the keyword in the search box. The suggestions need to be biased based on the past history of the user. We intend to pass the user’s profile to SOLR in the query, for e.g. if the user purchases electronics more often followed by biscuits, we will pass “electronics, biscuits”. SOLR is expected to suggest electronic products in the autocomplete box.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Yash

Answer (score 0):

You can add boosts to a query, so that any match in the category field results in the document beeing boosted differently depending on the weights.

i.e. using `category:electronics^4 category:biscuits^2` will result in electronics being boosted twice the amount of biscuits, which are boosted twice the amount of regular documents as well. Depending on your query handler, you can [use the `bq` parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebq(BoostQuery)Parameter) for adding queries that should boost documents. EDisMax also supports other boost parameters, although you shouldn't need those to solve this.